# Stop caching for a specific node (by nid) Drupal 7

Tags: caching, drupal-7, drupal-theming

Ideally i want to set custom params for caching in some particular nodes using conditions in my **template.php**

***E.g. algorithm:*** for node with known **nid** set custom caching params

But that's enough for my purpose simply exclude from caching particular node.
I fond this solution: [Stop caching for a specific node type Drupal 7](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/26938/) this is exacly what im looking for but how i can change condition of checking from node type to nid.

I know about [CacheExclude](https://www.drupal.org/project/cacheexclude) module, but for me unwanted to install module for just exclude one node for caching.

I'll be very grateful for helping me.

Answer (score 0):

As per the example you gave in the link, add a custom module, implement a hook_init function (don't forget to clear the cache when you do this) and add the following to the hook function:

```
$node = menu_get_object();
if (!empty($node) && $node->nid == '<NODE ID HERE>') {
  drupal_page_is_cacheable(false);
}
```